# QT Creator warnings on empty project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 4.12.0 with Qt 5.14.2 and GCC 5.3.1 and when I create a new project and build it without making any changes the there are about 32 warnings related to qvariant and qstyleoptions. if I include QVariant in the main file only one warning will be shown.

the warning after compiling with #include :

```
/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:265: warning: implicitly-declared 
‘QVariant::Private& QVariant::Private::operator=(const QVariant::Private&)’ is deprecated [- 
Wdeprecated-copy]
  265 |     { other.d = Private(); }
      |                         ^
```

why is this happening? I'm fairly new so I cannot figure out on my own.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2uCH4Nha full list of warnings when built without changing anything.

Comment: Strange that the warning message points to the older version of Qt: `/opt/Qt/5.9.9...`.

Comment: like vahancho noticed, it is quite probable you are not using Qt 5.14.2.